# database "Todolist" does not exist with postgresql on django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have created a database with the name Todolist, however I am getting the error "database does not exist" after using the command `python manage.py makemigrations`. I am using postgresql

[image]

Comment: Show us the database section from your `settings.py` file.

Comment: in general, it would be better to post your code as code snippet instead of using screenshots. But what happens if you run `psql -d Todolist -U todouser` in your terminal? This should prompt you the password and then open your postgres shell. If it doesn't, then your database settings are incorrect.

Comment: db user doesn't has access to given database